# C# - Is it possible? - [DescriptionAttribute()] with TextBox text

Tags: c#, enums, custom-attributes

Can a `DescriptionAttribute` in an enumeration contain a `TextBox`'es text? I ask because I have a file with numerous `TextBox`es and I was hoping to match the content of them with a value that I have. I doubt I can do this, but I'm not sure at all.

i.e.

```
[DescriptionAttribute(textBox1.Text)]
a,
```

Comment: Did you try it?  In the time that it took you to post this in StackOverflow, the compiler would have given you the error!

Comment: This question could be answered when trying to compile the code itself.

Comment: Yes I did try it, and I saw that it didn't work, but I thought that I may be going about it the wrong way; now, as I suspected, it has been shown not to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, attributes need compile time constants as parameters.

The C# specification says:

> An expression E is an attribute-argument-expression if all of the following statements are true:
>
> - The type of E is an attribute parameter type (§24.1.3).
> - At compile-time, the value of E can be resolved to one of the following:
>
>   - A constant value.
>   - A typeof-expression (§14.5.11) specifying a non-generic type, a closed constructed type (§25.5.2), or 
>       an unbound generic type (§25.5).
>   - A one-dimensional array of attribute-argument-expressions.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer.

Answer (score 2):

No that is no possible, since attributes are part of the assmebly's meta data, i.e. embedded in the *.dll/*.exe you're compiling.

You cannot, at compile time, refer to a value that will only exist at runtime.

If you want something even remotely like this, you'll have to build it for yourself, i.e., create a class that maps fields of an Enum to the values of textboxes **at runtime**.

Answer (score 1):

No. Attributes are defined at compile time and have to be constant values.